# Customize Lotus Notes 8.x Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lotus-notes

Does anyone know how to customize the shortcut keys in Lotus Notes?

Using Lotus Notes 8.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to that...

Comment: Which version of notes would you like them in?

Answer (score 4):

This 60-second AutoHotkey script will give you CTRL+R to reply to a message.  However, it requires that the current pane is the message list.  If you've clicked the preview pane, the menu commands don't work.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SWT_Window0 
{
  ^r::Send !ayr
return
}
```

Comment: How do you implement this??

Comment: install AutoHotKey @rh0dium.

Comment: FYI For Notes 8.5 with the preview pane active, I needed this sequence:

  ^r::Send !apye